# Android AAR containing multiple architectures built via cmake

Tags: android, cmake, android-ndk, aar

I am new to working with the NDK and I have a library project which contains:

```
...
        publications {
            mavenRelease(MavenPublication) {
                artifactId = "someLib"
                from components.release
            }
        }
...

    defaultConfig {
        ndk { abiFilters = ["x86", "..."] }
        ...
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                targets "default"
            }
        }
    }

    externalNativeBuild {
       cmake {
           path file('some/path/CMakeLists.txt')
           version '3.10.2'
       }
    }
```

which produces a library for a specific architecture.

My main problem is: I have a cpp project and I want to distribute built versions for each architecture via a private maven repo so my plan is to create a versioned AAR. Am I going in the right direction?

Is it possible to package multiple libX.so files for various architectures within an AAR? (relying on AAB + split abi)

Answer (score 0):

Basically, google play does it automatically
https://shoutem.com/blog/android-app-bundle-google-play-store/

Manually, you can do it via bundletool
https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/bundletool#manually_create_json